# Url to invoke the java web service

Tags: java, web-services, web

I have a web service as below. Any body please tell me what is the Url to invoke the getUserDetails();

....://localhost:8080/Jersey-Rest/rest/hellow /
I want the url after hellow/....

```
@Path("/hellow")
public class HelloWorldService {
 @GET
    @Path("/{name1}/{name2}/")
    public Response getUserDetails(@PathParam("name1") String name1,@PathParam("name2") String name2){
        String output = "User info ..  "+name1+name2 ;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

....://localhost:8080/Jersey-Rest/rest/hellow/joe/bob/ for example

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Huh?  He asked for a URL. Thus my answer is a URL.